# Bivariate Normal question?

Tags: probability, statistics

My teacher posted this question at the end of the class a while ago but we never ended up going back to it. My exam is soon so I was wondering if someone could help me.

Consider the Bivariate Normal on pg 81 of the book (look at picture below).[image] Prove that if p=0,then X and Y are independent.

Comment: Since $X\sim N(\mu_X, \sigma_X^2), Y\sim N(\mu_Y, \sigma_Y^2)$ you have equations for $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$.  So it is sufficient to show that when $\rho=0$ then $f(x,y) = f_X(x)\; f_Y(y)$.

Comment: I am still confused, what are the equations for f_x(x) and f_y(y)

Comment: They are the probability density functions of normal distributed variables with expectation and variance parameters as given.  $f_X(x) = \frac {1}{\sigma_x\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(\frac{-(x-\mu_X)^2}{2\sigma_X^2}\right)$.

Comment: Basically, to show that any bivariate probability density function is the joint distribution of two independent variables, show that it can be separated into the product of two monovariate probability distribution function in terms of each variable.

Comment: how do i do that, can u explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a bivariate normal probability density function with a correlation parameter $\rho$.

$$\begin{align}
f(x,y;\rho) & = \frac{1}{2\pi \sigma_{\small X} \sigma_{\small Y}\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\exp\left(\frac{-1}{2(1-\rho^2)}\left[\frac{(x-\mu_{\small X})^2}{\sigma_{\small X}^2}+\frac{(y-\mu_{\small Y})^2}{\sigma_{\small Y}^2}-\frac{2\rho(x-\mu_{\small X})(y-\mu_{\small Y})}{\sigma_{\small X}\sigma_{\small Y}}\right]\right)
\end{align}$$
When the parameter is equal to zero we have:
$$\begin{align}
f(x,y;0) & = \frac{1}{2\pi \sigma_{\small X} \sigma_{\small Y}}\exp\left(\frac{-1}{2}\left[\frac{(x-\mu_{\small X})^2}{\sigma_{\small X}^2}+\frac{(y-\mu_{\small Y})^2}{\sigma_{\small Y}^2}\right]\right)
\\[1ex]
& = \frac 1{\sigma_{\small X}\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(\frac{-(x-\mu_{\small X})^2}{2\sigma_{\small X}^2}\right)\times\frac 1{\sigma_{\small Y}\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(\frac{-(y-\mu_{\small Y})^2}{2\sigma_{\small Y}^2}\right)
\\[1ex]
& = f_N(x; \mu_{\small X}, \sigma_{\small X}^2)\times f_N(y; \mu_{\small Y}, \sigma_{\small Y}^2)
\end{align}$$
Where $f_N(z; \mu, \sigma^2)$ is the probability density function of a random variable$\\$ with a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.
$$\begin{align}
 f_N(z; \mu, \sigma^2) & := \frac 1{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(\frac{-(z-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)
\end{align}$$
Thus the joint probability density function $f(x,y;0)$ is the product of two monovariate probability density functions.   This is sufficient to identify these functions as the marginal probability density functions of each random variable, since by definition the marginal density is:
$$\begin{align}
f_X(x;0) & = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x,y;0)\operatorname d y
\\[1ex]
 & = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_N(x; \mu_{\small X}, \sigma_{\small X}^2)\times f_N(y; \mu_{\small Y}, \sigma_{\small Y}^2)\operatorname d y
\\[1ex]
 & = f_N(x; \mu_{\small X}, \sigma_{\small X}^2)\times \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_N(y; \mu_{\small Y}, \sigma_{\small Y}^2)\operatorname d y
\\[1ex]
 & = f_N(x; \mu_{\small X}, \sigma_{\small X}^2)
\end{align}$$
And likewise for $Y$ by symmetry.

Thus we have $f(x,y;0) = f_X(x;0)\;f_Y(y;0)$ which is necessary and sufficient to demonstrate independence of the random variables when the correllation parameter $\rho$ is equal to zero.